# Why are the constant fields un-protected?

Tags: javascript, constants, ecmascript-6

`const` can be used to declare constants:

```
> const a = 42
undefined
> a = 7
7
> a
42
```

This is cool, but I observed that when using `const` to declare objects this behavior doesn't work anymore:

```
> const b = { foo: { bar: 42 }, baz: 7 }
undefined
> b.baz = { hello: "world" }
{ hello: 'world' }
> b.foo.bar = 7
7
> b
{ foo: { bar: 7 }, baz: { hello: 'world' } }
```

As you can see, I modified the `baz` field into an object and I changed `42` into `7`.

Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) I see this is expected:

> ```
> // Overwriting the object fails as above (in Firefox and Chrome
> but not in Safari)
> MY_OBJECT = {"OTHER_KEY": "value"};
>
> // However, object attributes are not protected,
> // so the following statement is executed without problems
> MY_OBJECT.key = "otherValue";
> ```

However, why this is working like this? What is the logic behind?

On the other side, the question would be: how to declare constant objects?

Comment: const just prevents redeclaration of the var, what you seem to want is an immutable object , which plain js-objects are not - maybe this (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js)

Comment: *const just prevents redeclaration of the var* -- but if I *override* the constant, the value is not modified. Only by modifying a subfield the value changes.

Comment: @IonicăBizău No, the "value" of an object is its memory address.

Comment: well yes, if your "override" means "assign a value to a var"; then a const var cannot be assign a subsequent value. Thats one thing. But mutating a mutable value (i.e. object) - even if its assinged to const - will mutate it. At least thats how I understand it.

Comment: @birdspider If you like, post an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, why this is working like this? What is the logic behind?

`const` is only declaring a binding as constant. It doesn't automatically make every value that it is initialised with immutable.

> how to declare constant objects?

To prevent an object from being mutated, you can [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it:

```
"use strict";
const b = Object.freeze({foo: Object.freeze({bar: 42}), baz: 7});
b.baz = {hello: "world"}; // Error: Invalid assignment in strict mode
```